# Neo4j Fetch all Nodes and Relations between two given nodes

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

My database structure is like
A->B->C->D
There are multiple relations between all nodes. I need to query data so that it can give me all nodes & all relationships in between nodes.
My sample query is like 
A-[*]-D

The output I'm expecting is all relations and nodes between A to D which is B & C.
Is there any way to do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do.  The first thing that you'll want to do is assign a path variable like this:

```
MATCH path=(a:A)-[*]-(b:B)-[*]-(c:C)-[*]-(d:D)
```

Then you can either get the nodes, the relationships, or the whole path like this:

```
MATCH path=(a:A)-[*]-(b:B)-[*]-(c:C)-[*]-(d:D)
RETURN nodes(path), rels(path), path
```

Depending on how you're getting data from Neo4j what is returned in the third column (the path) will vary, but generally it should be a list of node, rel, node, rel, etc... and always starting and ending with a node.

Comment: Thanks @BrainUnderwood  for quick response, Actually above cypher got me all relations in between A and D node. But didn't got me node B & C. I used this cypher as
 MATCH path=(a:A)-[*1..2]-(d:D)
RETURN nodes(path), rels(path), path as it wasn't executing due to some java heap memory issue.
so with this one half of the problem solved now another half I'm looking into to get the nodes B & C.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was thinking that B and C just happened to be the nodes in between.  What about the query in my new edit?  Also keep in mind that variable relationships without limits can potentially have performance issues depending on your graph.  You may want to change to something like `[*1..5]` at some point

Comment: @Brain Thanks That seems working!!... but optimization is still required since my schema is some what more extended this chain is having 200+ nodes in between and in some cases I need to extract all 198 in between. I think I need to think of some other schema :( Can you suggest any I'm newbie to Neo?

Comment: Good question.  Maybe if you matched just `(a:A)-[*]-(b:B)` to start with and then passed the `path` and `b` variables using the `WITH` clause to then match `b-[*]-(c:C)`, pass on with `WITH`, etc...  If you're only matching on part of the path first then it might not need to consider so many possibilities

Comment: Got it !! Thanks a lot Brain :) I applied a different approach I created one common relation (which in data I already had) then applied the cypher 'code' MATCH path=(a:A)-[:myRelation*]-(d:D)
RETURN nodes(path), rels(path), path 'code'.